# Is there a mod_actions module like for Apache for GET request?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to execute a local (or remote (via http)) script when someone hits one of my website with GET request.

I saw the [mod_actions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_actions.html) module for Apache which would be great if it would also work for simple GET requests :

> Also note that Script with a method of GET will only be called if there are query arguments present (e.g., foo.html?hi). Otherwise, the request will proceed normally.

Is there an alternative to this module that would call a script with any GET request? The main thing I want to do is log data, so it's not a problem if the content of the renderer request is not given with it.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html ?

Comment: Thank you; does this will work for scripts with PHP after that? I just want to be notified when GET requests are made, but allow the normal flow of the request.